# Changing partner users profile gives out alert "No available Portal"

Tags: partner-portal

I am creating a new object to hold the news data. 
As per the documentation, we cannot edit the Gold Partner profile to provide access to this new object. We would need to clone this profile and then reassign the new profile to the user.

I have done this but changing the profile for the user and trying to login shows an alert “No available Portal”. Any thoughts on what should be done to provide access to portal

Answer (score 1):

I got a resolution for this just after i posted this question.

I needed to add this new profile to the portal as well and here is how you do it.

Go to Setup | Customize | Customer Portals.  Click on one of your portals.  You'll notice there's a related list there called "Assigned Profiles."  Select the newly created profile. These users' profile needs to have at least one portal assigned to it before the users can access a portal.